# Comment x-position is wrong

Tags: bug, comments, design, russian-stackoverflow

My [comment](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/626691/%D0%9D%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8B-imgui#comment877209_626691) on the question have weird x-offset now:

> [image: weird]

If I click on "add comment" link, then existing comment will be shifted to the left, and looks like any other comments anywhere else on SE:

> [image]

Comment: @Mithrandir you can test it anywhere you want. But it's reproduced only for mentioned comment :)

Comment: Dangit, where did I put that picture...

Comment: it is caused by table layout. need to define first column width to stable it for short comments.

Comment: @vp_arth you could write an answer here with possible implementation so developers can take it and.... ignore to use.

Answer (score 1):

```css
table{width: 100%}
```

```html
<h2>Issue:</h2>

<table border=1>
 <tr><td>Flg</td><td>Short</td></tr>
</table>

<h2>Solution:</h2>

<table border=1>
 <tr><td width=1>Flg</td><td>Short</td></tr>
 <tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td>ok</td></tr>
</table>
```