# Comment is shifted to the right

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments, design

[This comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8714250/isnt-const-redundant-when-passing-by-value#comment10846505_8714335) looks shifted to the right now:

> [image: now]

But according to the wayback machine [the comment used to look normal before](https://web.archive.org/web/20170222134511/http://stackoverflow.com:80/questions/8714250/isnt-const-redundant-when-passing-by-value#comment10846505_8714335):

> [image: before]

Comment: On Meta Stack Overflow: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359286

Comment: Simple fix: nuke the comment. A single flag will automatically delete it ;)

Comment: Possibly related or even duplicate of my older [bug report](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/290971/339911).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixed in the next build, see my answer on [There is more space at the left of a comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359286/there-is-more-space-at-the-left-of-a-comment/359596#359596) on MSO.

Comment: Which build is next? Comment still shifted.

Comment: I'll deploy in a few minutes.

Comment: @alexolut By the way, thanks for the current and archive link -- that was really helpful for finding the issue.

Comment: np. You're welcome. Just fix bugs what I [posted already](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A339911+-%5Bstatus-*%5D+%5Bbug%5D). :)